# What does 'Ign', 'Get' or 'Hit' mean when running an apt-get update?

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, repository

I had a bunch of errors in the output of sudo apt-get update:  duplicate entries and 404 not found errors.

Figured those out, I hope: I removed PPAs that didn't have any packages associated with them, then I removed out a duplicate entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

It seems I have royally buggered it up.  Now most of the lines say *Ign* when I do `sudo apt-get update`.

How do I go about straightening out what I have screwed up?  I need to get rid of these `Ign`s that are all over the place.  There are about 50% (eyeball guess) `Ign`s!

Comment: It means: **Ign**ore

Answer (score 92, accepted):

When you use `apt-get update` it verifies if the same update indexes need downloading, if not it does not download the same updated indexes again.

- `Hit` means apt checked the timestamps on package list, those match and there are no changes.
- `Ign` means there are no changes in the pdiff index file, it wont bother downloading it again.
- `Get` means apt checked the timestamps on package list, there were changes and will be downloaded.

Nothing to be scared of, it just means there is no need to download updated indexes again, the ones you have are current.

Comment: AFAIK the list of packages is contained in the **packages.gz/bz2** file in the repo. So, does your answer means that: **Hit** stand for checking the timestamp of packages.gz file and its Ok. And if time stamps are mismatched then it checks the contents of the packages.gz file literally to match with my computers cache, if found all packages then gives **Ign**, otherwise update that repo cache. If i am not right then could you be more specific for me?

Comment: This appears to contradict http://superuser.com/questions/454867/how-do-ign-and-hit-affect-apt-get-update which says that Ign is an error condition.

Comment: I've looked at the source file acqprogress.cc from "apt" and it too appears contradictory: it outputs "Ign" `if (Itm.Owner->Status == pkgAcquire::Item::StatDone)` - StatDone means the file has downloaded (cf acquire-item.h) but the block where Ign is output is an error handling block for failed downloads ... it's seemingly beyond my beginner coding comprehension. Just flagging the contradiction with superuser.com though.

Comment: This answer is not correct. `Ign` means that `apt` tried to download something (such as translation or `InRelease` file) but didn't found, but that can be ignored. Proceed to the next thing. `Hit` means `apt` needed to download a `Release` file (because somehow it got deleted) and once it is downloaded, It checks the checksum of the Package file and found that the checksum mentioned in the newly downloaded `Release` file matches with the checksum of the Package file already there. It's a `Hit`. So, it won't download the `Package` file again.

Comment: Just to make this clearer, this doesn't mean that this is not a "problem"? Why does this show up everytime i `apt-get update`? Just confuses me :S

Answer (score 38):

The correct answer of this question is:

- `Ign` means `apt` tried to download something (such as translation or `InRelease` file) but didn't find, but that can be ignored, so proceed to the next thing. Because translation can be secondary priority and if `InRelease` file can't be found, it uses other method for authentication like using `Release` and `Release.gpg` pair.
- `Hit` means `apt` needed to download a `Release` file or `InRelease` file (because somehow it got deleted) and once it is downloaded, it checked the checksum of the Index file in it and found that the checksum mentioned there matches the checksum of the Package file already downloaded that is in `/var/lib/apt/lists`. That's why it's a `Hit`. So, it won't download the `Package` file again.

---

Found the answer from:

- [How do Ign and Hit affect apt-get update](https://superuser.com/questions/454867/how-do-ign-and-hit-affect-apt-get-update)
- My personal experiment with a local repository by turning off all other repositories.

Comment: The `get` information provided in the other answer is correct?