# Verifying that Google Chrome is updating in 16.04 LTS

Tags: updates, google-chrome

I've been using Google Chrome (with 16.04) and want to verify that I'm keeping it properly updated. Using `sudo apt-get update` I obtain the following messages (along with other expected "get" messages for various repositories):

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
```

Also, the last 3 lines of the output from apt-get were:

```
Fetched 1,166 kB in 3s (360 kB/s)   
AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors.
Reading package lists... Done
```

Does this indicate that the Chrome update has occurred?

If not, where should I look to verify the update?

Also, I was wondering what the message about ignored metadata means? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `Ign` and `Hit` doesn't mean that the Chrome Update has occured. See below [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/815869/253251) from @Anwar.

> - `Hit` means `apt` needed to download a `Release` file or `InRelease` file (because somehow it got deleted) and once it is downloaded, it checked the checksum of the Index file in it and found that the checksum mentioned there matches the checksum of the Package file already downloaded that is in `/var/lib/apt/lists`. That's why it's a `Hit`. So, it won't download the Package file again.
> - `Ign` means `apt` tried to download something (such as translation or `InRelease` file) but didn't find, but that can be ignored, so proceed to the next thing. Because translation can be secondary priority and if `InRelease` file can't be found, it uses other method for authentication like using `Release` and `Release.gpg` pair.

Nor the `AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors.` cause update to chrome, it was a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1644498).

To check whether chrome is updated. Click the Chrome menu  on the browser toolbar and select About Google Chrome.

[image]