# Sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates, kubuntu, 18.10

I’m running Kubuntu 18.10 and when I run  `sudo apt-get update`, I see 3 update-able:

```
http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease[83.2kb ]
http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/Ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease [74.6kb]
https://security.ubuntu.com/Ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease [83.2kb]
```

Then when I run `sudo apt-get upgrade`, it says 0 to upgrade:

```
0 to newly install and 0 to remove  and 0 to upgrade
```

But on my first command `sudo apt-get update`, I see 3 get listed above and when I run the update, I get the *0 to upgrade 0 to Newly install, etc.*

Am I missing something? I am new to Linux. Someone help please much appreciated.

Comment: Try `sudo apt update` and follow that up with `sudo apt full-upgrade`. The "full" is important.

Comment: What is the exact output? Try to copy complete output and paste it in question body. If there are any packages to be upgraded they can be listed by `apt list --upgradable`.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [edit] the question to make the title more descriptive, and add the *exact* outputs you get, with [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to make it look nice.

Comment: I think you're confusing repos with packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `apt-get update` looks like this:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease       
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease         
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Or:

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease [242 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease [83.2 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/multiverse amd64 Packages [195 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/restricted amd64 Packages [13.6 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe amd64 Packages [11.6 MB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages [1342 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [1075 B]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [218 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 Packages [146 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports/universe amd64 Packages [3019 B]
Fetched 14.0 MB in 5s (2835 kB/s)                          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

That doesn't mean that there are packages that can be updated (as the last line explicitly says). What you are seeing is `apt` fetching package lists from the repositories. But the package lists tell apt that there are no new versions of the software that's installed on your system, and so there's nothing to upgrade.

See also:

- [What does "sudo apt-get update" do?](https://askubuntu.com/q/222348/158442)
- [What does 'Ign' or 'Hit' mean when running an apt-get update?](https://askubuntu.com/q/294525/158442)

Comment: I see, All Packages are up to date, at the bottom, but what is it with,    GET:

Comment: I thought GET: means you dont have it, GET: it, as such

Comment: "Get" here is apt telling you what it's doing (getting the package lists of that repository).

Answer (score 0):

`apt` is responsible for maintaining the release/version tracking of packages. It reads the package repositories list in /etc/apt/sources.list file and reads/compares each time apt-get update is called. It compares the local package with the repository, verifies dependencies and produces results at the end of execution. You can check which package needs to be upgraded using the command `apt list --upgradable`