# update shows a lot off ignored Sources

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

since some days I get a very strange output when trying to update my Ubuntu system:

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jcfp/nobetas/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                 
Hit:3 https://deb.troglobit.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                                                                            
Hit:4 https://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease                                                                                                                
Get:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                      
Get:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]      
Get:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease [114 kB]       
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit:12 https://repo.jellyfin.org/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/multiverse amd64 Packages
Err:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
Get:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 Packages [1396 kB]
Get:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main Translation-en [358 kB]
Get:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [1178 kB]
Get:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [1178 kB]
Get:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [1178 kB]
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:21 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:21 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:21 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:21 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:23 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:21 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Err:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:23 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:21 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:23 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:23 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:23 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Err:22 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Get:23 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages [104 kB]
Get:23 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages [104 kB]
Get:23 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages [104 kB]
Get:23 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages [104 kB]
Get:23 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages [104 kB]
Get:23 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages [104 kB]
Ign:23 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:30 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:31 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:32 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:33 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:30 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:31 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:32 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:33 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:30 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:31 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:32 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:33 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:30 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:31 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:32 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:33 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:30 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:31 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:32 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:33 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Err:30 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Ign:31 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:32 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:33 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Fetched 336 kB in 3s (122 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What can I do? Some days ago I never got that much Hit, Get, Ignore, whatever messages.

This is my architecture:

```
wolf@frida:/etc/apt$ lscpu
Architecture:                    aarch64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
CPU(s):                          4
```

This is my sources.list:

```
wolf@frida:/etc/apt$ cat sources.list
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal main restricted
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security multiverse
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 'Ign', 'Get' or 'Hit' mean when running an apt-get update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294525/what-does-ign-get-or-hit-mean-when-running-an-apt-get-update)  Be sure to read both answers, not just the accepted one.

Comment: Thx for link but no. I mean some days ago I got less than 10 lines printed and not 80 lines with Ignore, several with Error, and 4 with Failed. So something happend - I don't know what.

Answer (score 1):

The ports.ubuntu.com repository is for ports to **non-** amd64 architectures: arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, and s390x.

They don't have amd64 packages there.

You chose the lone repository on Earth that won't work with your amd64 system, so simply choose ANY other repo.

Comment: But my system is:  
`wolf@frida:/etc/apt$ lscpu` 
`Architecture:                    aarch64`  
`CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit`  
`Byte Order:                      Little Endian`

Comment: @exaveal look at your `apt update` output lines: You are asking your apt sources for amd64 packages, not aarch64 packages. It might be useful for you to ask a new question about how to fix your wrong architecture in apt, since that requires a bit of troubleshooting. For the question that you *originally* asked, this is an appropriate answer.