Ubuntu 24.04 installer is stuck
today I wanted to install Ubuntu 24.04 and dualboot it with Windows 10.
This was the first time ever installing  an operating system. I am doing this on a laptop HP 820 G3 that gets the minimal requirements for Ubuntu. But the installer gor stuck on Setting the system up. On an command Got:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease. I know how to do stuff of Windows, but Ubuntu is new. The installer is running by now for 3,5 hours and it will be running through night. Thanks for upcoming help.picture_of_console

you enabled downloading from internet, see this https://askubuntu.com/questions/294525/what-does-ign-get-or-hit-mean-when-running-an-apt-get-update I would just let it finish.

@amar yeah but its stuck over 15 hours by now

is it still at downloading? does your internet work?

and what is your version of Windows?

@amar no it is not downloading and my Windows version is Windows 10 22H2(probably). We restarted the laptop and Ubuntu said: Please remove installation media and then press ENTER. So I removed it and pressed enter, then it booted successfully. I started to install libreoffice suite, and then I powered off my laptop (normally through Ubuntu) to check if I successfully dualbooted Windows with Ubuntu. When I tried powering it back on, my HP laptop doesn't boot (it wont let me even go to BIOS/UEFI), it just displays an error on keyboard: once every second CapsLock blinks and the "Internet ON/OFF"

*is lightning orange, that means that there is a problem with CPU, fans are not spinning too

Sorry Radek but it seems that you have a hardware problem. may be you can ask someone to look at it unfortunately hardware problems as you describe are not a part of this forum and anyway you will need a person present.
